# Gradle Build error when trying to build for Meta Quest 2

Tags: android, unreal-engine4, virtual-reality, oculusquest

A minute ago, I made a new VR test project in Unreal Engine 4.27.2, on my M1 MacBook Pro because I wanted to make a VR game for the <strike>Oculus</strike> Meta Quest 2 so I thought the VR template would be good, so I chose that.

I immediately went to build as soon as the project was finished initializing but then it failed with this error:

```
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): ERROR: /bin/sh failed with args -c '"/Users/[me]/Desktop/PROJECTS/UNREAL_ENG4/FunQuestGame/Intermediate/Android/arm64/gradle/gradlew" :app:assembleDebug'
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):        (see /Users/[me]/Library/Logs/Unreal Engine/LocalBuildLogs/Log.txt for full exception trace)
PackagingResults: Error: /bin/sh failed with args -c '"/Users/[me]/Desktop/PROJECTS/UNREAL_ENG4/FunQuestGame/Intermediate/Android/arm64/gradle/gradlew" :app:assembleDebug'
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=1 (Error_Unknown)
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): RunUAT ERROR: AutomationTool was unable to run successfully.
PackagingResults: Error: AutomationTool was unable to run successfully.
PackagingResults: Error: Unknown Error
```

[Here is the log file](https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/raw/oroyezijav). The error is at the bottom, I literally just pasted the whole log in there, sorry for it being so long.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue.
Do the following:
Open task manager and terminate `automationtool` before building.

Comment: 'M1 MacBook Pro', not Windows PC